# Delay from a Database in a custom flowchart

Tags: anylogic

I would like to use my custom flowchart for different process flows and the delay time of my process is coming from a database. I tried to use the parameter but doesn't work. How can I get access to my database and connect it with my delay block in my custom flowchart to get my delay from the dbase. My target is to pick my pallets from the racks to the certain times.
delaytime =timearrival_minutes

[image: custom_flowchart]

[image: truck]

Answer (score 1):

Use a DynamicEvent.

Create a function at the model start that loops across all dbase entries. Create a dynamic event for each entry that is triggered by "the dbase-entry date" minus "your current model start date".

In the Dynamic Event, trigger `rawMaterialStorage.free(some agent)`, obviously it is up to you to free from the correct custom block.

Check example models and the help on looping dbase entries and Dynamic Events :)